# Why did Clark go to Nevada?

Tags: dc, superman, smallville

In the Smallville Episode "Unsafe" (S04E11) ,  Alicia Baker "drugs" Clark by giving him red kryptonite and then they decide to get married. We then skip to a scene in a chapel where Alicia and Clark get married. At this point we hear the Father say " By the Power vested in me by the state of Nevada...."

My question is why did they go to Nevada to get married?? They could have gotten married in Kansas or could have gone to California (where Alicia wanted to go) to get married? Why Nevada???

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Las Vegas, Nevada traditionally has a reputation as being known for being the place for impulsive or quick weddings. Add in Las Vegas' nickname of "Sin City" and you have a thematic reason for them to go there - what better way for them to showcase Clark having no inhibition than sending him there for a quick marriage?

Over half of the states in the United States have [waiting periods for marriage licenses](http://usmarriagelaws.com/search/united_states/waiting_period_marriage_license/index.shtml). This waiting period means that couples cannot get married on a whim. As you can probably guess, Nevada is not one of those states, while Kansas is.

So, why Nevada versus any one of the other states which don't have a waiting period? Most likely just because of [the reputation](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/VivaLasVegas) (warning: tv tropes link). Why didn't they stay in Kansas? Honestly, still probably because Vegas is where "everyone" goes to elope, but Kansas also has a three day waiting period. This would make the whole thing a lot less "spontaneous".